# Very subtle HLSL syntax change causes compliation error

Tags: shaders, hlsl

The following HLSL works and compiles:

```
texture2D renderTarget;
float h; // declared here

sampler GetRenderTarget = sampler_state
{
    texture = <renderTarget>;
};

float3 GetHsvFromRgb(float3 c)
{
    float4 k = float4(0.0, -1.0 / 3.0, 2.0 / 3.0, -1.0);
    float4 p = lerp(float4(c.bg, k.wz), float4(c.gb, k.xy), step(c.b, c.g));
    float4 q = lerp(float4(p.xyw, c.r), float4(c.r, p.yzx), step(p.x, c.r));
    float d = q.x - min(q.w, q.y);
    float e = 1.0e-10;

    return float3(abs(q.z + (q.w - q.y) / (6.0 * d + e)), d / (q.x + e), q.x);
}

float3 GetRgbFromHsv(float3 c)
{
    float4 k = float4(1.0, 2.0 / 3.0, 1.0 / 3.0, 3.0);
    float3 p = abs(frac(c.xxx + k.xyz) * 6.0 - k.www);

    return c.z * lerp(k.xxx, clamp(p - k.xxx, 0.0, 1.0), c.y);
}

float4 ShadeVertex(float3 p : POSITION0, inout float2 t : TEXCOORD0) : POSITION0
{
    return float4(p, 1);
}

float4 ShadePixel(float4 p : POSITION0, float2 t : TEXCOORD0) : COLOR0
{
    float4 c = tex2D(GetRenderTarget, t);
    float3 hsv = GetHsvFromRgb(c);

    hsv.x = (int)h; // compiles and works

    float3 rgb = GetRgbFromHsv(hsv);

    return float4(rgb, h);
}

technique Simple
{
    pass FirstPass
    {
        VertexShader = compile vs_3_0 ShadeVertex();
        PixelShader = compile ps_3_0 ShadePixel();
    }
}
```

However, if I remove the cast from the `h` variable it causes an exception:

```
float4 ShadePixel(float4 p : POSITION0, float2 t : TEXCOORD0) : COLOR0
{
    float4 c = tex2D(GetRenderTarget, t);
    float3 hsv = GetHsvFromRgb(c);

    hsv.x = h; // removing int cast causes compilation exception

    float3 rgb = GetRgbFromHsv(hsv);

    return float4(rgb, h);
}
```

This doesn't really make any sense to me. The `h` variable is being set to 1 in code. The int cast is not what I actually want to do, I was just testing various things trying to understand why I couldn't assign the `h` variable value directly. Exception I get after removing the int cast is:

> (51,18): ID3DXEffectCompiler::CompileEffect: There was an error compiling expression

More confusingly, if I cast to a float, it goes back to not working:

```
float4 ShadePixel(float4 p : POSITION0, float2 t : TEXCOORD0) : COLOR0
{
    float4 c = tex2D(GetRenderTarget, t);
    float3 hsv = GetHsvFromRgb(c);

    hsv.x = (float)h; // also an exception

    float3 rgb = GetRgbFromHsv(hsv);

    return float4(rgb, h);
}
```

Not sure what is going on or what I'm doing wrong, any insight?

Comment: I don't see any code where you assign a value to `h`. Could it be that uninitialized float is a problem for HLSL?

Comment: @KromStern It's set to 1 in code.

Comment: Where? Please point that line.

Comment: @KromStern Sorry, it's through the Effect.Parameters in XNA, not in the actual HLSL.